# не подключается css. Что делать?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

файл существует, формат css без всякого txt, подключен вроде корректно, в самом css
файле ошибок вроде тоже нет. В html файле работает css
файл html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

<title> test </title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="2.ico" type="image/x-icon">

<h1> test </h1>

  </head>
  <body>
<div class=square>
<style type = text/css>
body{
 background-color: #4682B4
}

  </body>
</html>
```

файл css:

```
.h1{
  position:
   top:90px; left:130px;
}

.square{
  position: relative; top:150px; left:350px;
width: 1200px;
height: 700px;
background: white;
border-radius: 10px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сейчас попытаюсь сказать что-то умное, но на самом деле какая-та фигня ^-^
Не судите строго)

```
//Стиль для классов, у тебя тег, без точки
  //Не так .h1{ ... }
  //А так h1{ ... }
//Где стиль и точка с запятой ?
  //Не так 
  .h1{
    position:
    top:90px; left:130px;
  }
  //А так 
  .h1{
    position:relative;
     top:90px; left:130px;
  }
//
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло. Текст не поменял позицию.

Comment: и закройте стиль перед <body> вот так `</style></body></html>`

Comment: спасибо, не увидел.  Но как текст сдвинуть, он вообще не реагирует, любые значения ставлю - он не двигается

Comment: а всё, решил, спасибо!

Comment: а в чём была ошибка?

Comment: я переписал вручную код css и строчку с привязкой css файла. Наверное букву какую-то на русском написал.